# about taking an input in vector in Java

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I have tried to take input in Java language through the vector method. I have tried these two different methods and just want to know the difference between:

```
Vector v = new Vector();

v.addElement(new Integer(10));
```

vs

```
v.add(10);
```

Comment: Did you read the JavaDoc? I guess not since it clearly states for `addElement()`: "This method is identical in functionality to the add(E) method (which is part of the List interface)."

Comment: Besides that, there are a few differences, the main one being that the first adds the number 10 while the latter adds 1.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addElement(E)

Comment: @Thomas Don't forget to add that the methods have different names.  One has "Element" in the name while the other doens't.

Comment: except the input 1 or 10, both doing the same job... so why the syntax is diffferent

Comment: Well, that's happening quite often when software evolves. The JavaDoc on `add` states that it exists since Java 1.2 so without digging deeper into history I'd guess that before that there was only `addElement()` which then was kept for downward compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addElement` and `add` are equivalent, although the return types differ.

However in your case the *overall* behaviour will be different due to your writing `new Integer(10)` in one case and `1` in the other case.

In the former case, a new `Integer` is created with the value 10 and a reference to that is pushed onto the container.

In the latter case, 1 will is auto-boxed to an `Integer`. But its value just happens to be within the range of *interned* integers (-128 to +127). So no new `Integer` is actually created, but a reference to one of the interned integers is pushed onto the container.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in function between`addElement()` and `add()`, except that `add()` returns a boolean.

From the JavaDoc for [`addElement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#addElement-E-):

> Adds the specified component to the end of this vector, increasing its size by one. The capacity of this vector is increased if its size becomes greater than its capacity.
>   This method is identical in functionality to the [`add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add-E-) method (which is part of the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface).

---

In relation to the boolean that is returned by `add()`, this is defined in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add-E-) as returning true if the collection has been changed by the method.
Put another way, this returns true if the element was added to the vector, and false otherwise.